# How do i merge git branch from dev to staging then production

Tags: git, drupal-7, bitbucket

I have just inherited a Drupal project and haven't used git in a while and I have no previous developer to speak to. There are two branches production and staging and equivalent hosting environments.

Would this be a correct workflow:

Git clone repo
Git checkout staging branch
Git pull origin staging
Git create and checkout new feature branch
Git checkout staging branch and merge
Git push to repo

On staging server
Git checkout staging
Git pull origin staging

Assuming this is correct how do I get my changes on to the production branch?

Answer (score 1):

Getting code from develop branch to staging branch:

`git clone repo
git checkout staging
git pull origin develop:staging
git commit -m "Commit to Staging"
git push`

Getting code from staging to master:

`git checkout master
git pull origin staging: master
git commit -m "Commit to master"
git push`

Comment: Thanks. that sounds good except for the fact that the develop branch would be on the same system. So wouldnt I need to git merge? Unless I pushed my develop branch up and pulled it back?

Comment: I would suggest pushing develop up first then so that central repository has the correct commit history. Commit to develop and then to staging and master.